# Como relacionar uma coluna A com B onde a coluna B começa com caracteres especiais?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho o `df` igual indicado na imagem, e gostaria que o usuário pesquisasse o elemento da coluna B e retornasse o elemento da coluna A correspondente...
O que consegui fazer foi o inverso somente, pesquisar um elemento de A e retornar o B...
O código que fiz relacionando coluna A com B:

```
dados.loc[dados['A']=='ALAR\AGUA_EXAUSTOR_15MH']['B']
```

Tentei transformar os dados de B em `str` mas só consegui com `json()`, o que não me ajudou muito.

EDIT: Consegui resolver e avançar no que precisava fazendo um replace no caracteres especiais. Vou manter a dúvida aqui pela curiosidade de saber se da certo direto sem fazer replace.

Obrigado a quem responder e desculpa a formatação da pergunta pois é minha primeira.

Comment: Sua pergunta não faz sentido, veja o [Exemplo Mínimo Completo e Verificável de sua pergunta](https://ideone.com/0GZrUO), **não apresenta problema algum**. A única dificuldade que tive foi memorizar a tabela que colocou como imagem para evitar ficar trocando de aba, no navegador, ao copiar os dados duma imagem onde deveria ter pensado na pessoa que se interessasse por sua pergunta e disponibilizado um [MCVE].

Comment: Desculpe por não ter sido mais claro na dúvida de fato e não ter disponibilzado o ` df `.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiz um exemplinho do que você deseja.

Uma opção é você filtrar o dado e em seguida passar a coluna que deseja e tem mais 2 maneiras que é o loc e iloc.

```
import pandas as pd

dados = [
         ['Indefinido', 0]
        ,['Domingo',1]
        ,['Segunda-Feira',2]
        ,['Terça-Feira',3]
        ,['Quarta-Feira',4]
        ,['Quinta-Feira',5]
        ,['Sexta-Feira',6]
        ,['Sábado',7]
        ]

df = pd.DataFrame(dados,columns=['Dia','Numero'])
print (df)
print()

numero = int(input("Digite um número: "))

'''
#Tratamento
if numero<1 or numero > 7:
    numero = 0
'''

#Filtragem
print(df['Dia'][df.Numero==numero].to_string())
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]